# How do I apply HStack to an array of views?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am kicking the tires of SwiftUI and want to make some functional versions of `HStack`.
However, I ran into a little problem. Namely the error:

```
Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'
```

A minimal example that produces this error:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

func row(_ views: Array<any View>) -> some View {
    HStack() {
        ForEach(0..<views.count) {
            views[$0]    // the error is here
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to fix the example?

Comment: Views should not be held as arrays, also swiftui does not do well with existentials you should stick with concrete types. look into `ViewBuilder`, ranges are also considered unsafe, you should watch "Demystify SwiftUI" there are common SwiftUI-beginner misconceptions especially coming from other languages.

Comment: Where can I see what `HStack` expands to?

Comment: You can't, it is nearly impossible because of the complexity of the types, a view type without a `ViewBuilder` can have many layers; a layer for each view, modifier and type; SwiftUI is model based you pass around model data and create views based on that data. You don't pass around views.

Comment: Definitely the first comment: keep data in arrays, build views with that data. Don't hold arrays of views

Comment: In my use case, the Views were the data. I am looking into implementing Hendersons picture language, and wanted to see whether the pictures could be represented as Views. I have decided to use a different approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make `row` generic over a concrete type, like so:

```
func row<Content>(_ views: [Content]) -> some View where Content: View {
    HStack() {
        ForEach(Array(0 ..< views.count), id: \.self) {
            views[$0]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it restricts `row` to views of the same type.
That is `row([Text("Hello"), Image(systemName: "globe")])` doesn't work

Comment: I have accepted this answer, since it is the most practal answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this way :

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

 func row(views: some View) -> some View {
        HStack() {
            views
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        row(views: Group {
       // Put whatever views you want here:
            Circle()
            Spacer()
            Circle()
        })
    }
```